# Java Simple RMI Chat Application

Tags: java, chat, rmi

I am trying to make a **very simple** chat program using **RMI** (*no GUI's*) but i am struggling for ideas.
How do i register clients when they connect to the server?
When i use

> RemoteServer.getClientHost()

all this does is show the ip address (and they are the same for all clients that connect from the same computer (from multiple command windows).
What i am trying to implement is this: when a client logs on he is shown a switch-case menu and ift they press

> 1. they get a list of connected clients.
> 2. sendMessage(client, String)

But i do not know how to identify individual clients?

And when i do, how do i show a string only on that client's window ?

Thanks,

*Research:
(i have looked at ideas on the web but a lot of them are more advanced than i want.
This is a simple application and i do not want to complicate it / copy code i dont understand).
There are previous questions on SO but with 0/1 answers (not very popular topic!) or not helpful!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i found what i was looking for:

**RMI Callback**

Basically making every client a server, so the server can respond as well as receive messages.

I have been directed to a resource that might help:

[Java Network Programming and Distributed Computing by David Reilly & Michael Reilly](http://www.dct.udn.vn/daotao/Resource/82487.pdf)

Comment: While embedding pdf links, you should be explicit - "This is a pdf link."